# How to get a videos with multiple videocategoryid using youtube api

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I have used Search: list operation to fetch a videos. When I add multiple videocategoryid to fetch videos, I get a response contain a **invalidSearchFilter error**.

Can you please help me to fetch videos from related category ids.

> request -
>   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=viewCount&videoCategoryId=2,20&key={API_KEY}

Comment: Please elaborate on exactly what commands you have tried so far.

Comment: using curl method...i want to display list with assign category ids....like both category id - 2 and 20....